# Uncaught SyntaxError:Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to import a module that is called `fs` and I used `require` to import it.  I then realized that to be able to use `require` I need to import it using this:

```
import {createRequire} from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
```

but it gives me this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: (Is it _in_ a module?)

Comment: Please share more details about your setup. Where is this code running (browser, server, …)? How did you load it, how did you start the program?

Comment: `fs` is filesystem. Your browser cannot access that, it's only available in Node.

Answer (score -1):

You need to assign the module property in script tag.

```
<script type="module">
     import { createRequire } from './module.js';
</script>
```